# iOS app crashes on start when using Kotlin/Native framework + ktor 1.3.2

Tags: ios, ktor, kotlin-native

When trying to start iOS app with included Kotlin/Native framework it is crashing on start with log

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _in6addr_linklocal_allv2routers
```

I am using latest releases of Kotlin/Native and ktor.

Config:

Kotlin/Native (multiplatform) 1.3.71

ktor 1.3.2

```
api("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
api("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktorVersion")
```

This crash is not reproduced with ktor 1.3.0

Please also note that I am even not using ktor classes in shared module (it is literally empty) nor in iOS app project.

Running with XCode 11.4, on iOS simulator v12.4

Comment: Hello, can you tell me what's your Xcode and iOS versions? Seems there was a similar [problem](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130632) in a recent release.

Comment: Also, please try to disable compiler caches by adding `kotlin.native.cacheKind=none` to the `gradle.properties` file in the project's root directory.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev thanks a lot, it works with `kotlin.native.cacheKind=none`. Does this setting increase build time or might influence a build somehow else?

Comment: Caches were introduced in Kotlin 1.3.70 as a new feature to speed-up the compilation and can be buggy a bit for now. Switching it off can lead to some time growth. It's even turned on only for debug builds, not for release ones.
One more thing I got to ask you - is it possible to share this project or a smaller reproducer to the Kotlin/Native team? Doing this would help a lot with the fix.

Comment: UPD: Oh, wow! I just found it should be already fixed. The same issue was reported on YouTrack, see [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38045). Please try to turn the cache on with Kotlin 1.3.72.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Cool! It works with Kotlin 1.3.72 )